# Stream pipelines in apache beam

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, pipeline, apache-beam

I have a file that is close to the 200mb, and I am reading it like this:

```
Lines = p | ReadFromText('file.ppl')
```

I want to know if I have to wait until the file is read in its entitity to apply the next transform or, if  the read transform reads a line, this line is inmidiately passed to the next transform like a stream chain.

What I want to do is pass a file(batch, because I know the size of the file and theres only one file per job) and then apply another transform to the resultant pcollection in a 'streaming' way (what I mean by "streaming way" is that, line that gets read line that gets processed so I dont have to wait until all the lines get proccesed to apply the next transform)

I'm a bit confused about how this works so thank you in advance if you can help me to clarify.

Comment: If I am not wrong, it reads line by line. If you look at the word count example for python sdk, in point 2 there is a sentence "The input for this transform is the PCollection of text lines generated by the previous TextIO.Read transform" which supports the fact that it is a line of text from the file used for reading the data.
Look at Figure 1. in this tutorial: https://beam.apache.org/get-started/wordcount-example/